# Fragments and Full Sentences.

Tags: adjectives, commas, sentence-fragments, is-it-a-sentence

"Popular museum located in an old warehouse."

Is this a complete sentence?

I feel it could become one by changing it to "A popular museum, located in an old warehouse."

Comment: Your amended version would work as a photo caption or similar, but as Martin states in his answer, it lacks the main verb necessary to transform it from a sentence fragment into a complete sentence.

Comment: The sentence is the equivalent of "Chocolate cookie placed in a big jar". A comma marks a pause. Why would a pause after 'cookie' create a predicate?

Answer (score 0):

It can be converted into a full sentence by prefacing it with "It is a". A full sentence must have a finite verb. The *located* merely adds a past participle to the otherwise incomplete sentence.

Comment: How if *located* be read as simple past and intransitive, rather than past/passive participle of transitive verb? OED does list an intransitive use (#4). Granted, an article would still be needed for *museum.*

Comment: I apologise for having read your two sentences incorrectly. The difference was the indefinate article "A". However, the insertion of the article still does not make the sentance grammatical. With respect to saying that "located" is past simple and not a past participle, you would have to ask what the museum located in a warehoue. "To locate" is a transitive verb and must have a direct object.

Comment: As I noted, OED does list an intransitive use: "4. *intr.* for *refl.* To establish oneself in a place; to settle." Taking *museum* to be at once a kind of corporation or collectivity of human beings and a collection of specimens and/or artifacts, one could just make out a case for a museum (the people) deciding to situate the museum (the collection) in an old warehouse. I admit it is a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

"Popular museum located in an old warehouse " looks like a telegraphic style of writing.

> It may have been used in a newspaper headline, a touristic map, a brochure about places of interest, etc.

To turn it into a complete sentence I would add some more information and a main verb.

> - "This is a popular museum located in an old warehouse"  (or whatever you might want to add)